# How calculate distance and travel time waypoints API Directions

Tags: java, android

I try to build an app, that calculate distance and travel time from origin + destination + waypoints, but only it's show me the first leg, I need to add all the legs

Here is the json :

```
{
     "distance" : {
                      "text" : "1.3 km",
                      "value" : 1313
                   },
                   "duration" : {
                      "text" : "5 min",
                      "value" : 278
                   }, {
                   "distance" : {
                      "text" : "1.9 km",
                      "value" : 1854
                   },
                   "duration" : {
                      "text" : "7 min",
                      "value" : 405
                   },
```

i need add **1.3km + 1.9km** and that result of this, be the value that gives me back **3.2km** like total distance, and the same with the time travel.

below fragment code of the directionfinder.java that show distance and travel time

```
  private void parseJSon(String data) throws JSONException {
        if (data == null)
            return;

        List<Route> routes = new ArrayList<Route>();
        JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject(data);
        JSONArray jsonRoutes = jsonData.getJSONArray("routes");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonRoutes.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonRoute = jsonRoutes.getJSONObject(i);
            Route route = new Route();

            JSONObject overview_polylineJson = jsonRoute.getJSONObject("overview_polyline");
            JSONArray jsonLegs = jsonRoute.getJSONArray("legs");
            JSONObject jsonLeg = jsonLegs.getJSONObject(0);
            JSONObject jsonDistance = jsonLeg.getJSONObject("distance");
            JSONObject jsonDuration = jsonLeg.getJSONObject("duration");
            JSONObject jsonEndLocation = jsonLeg.getJSONObject("end_location");
            JSONObject jsonStartLocation = jsonLeg.getJSONObject("start_location");


            route.distance = new Distance(jsonDistance.getString("text"), jsonDistance.getInt("value"));
            route.duration = new Duration(jsonDuration.getString("text"), jsonDuration.getInt("value"));
            route.endAddress = jsonLeg.getString("end_address");
            route.startAddress = jsonLeg.getString("start_address");
            route.startLocation = new LatLng(jsonStartLocation.getDouble("lat"), jsonStartLocation.getDouble("lng"));
            route.endLocation = new LatLng(jsonEndLocation.getDouble("lat"), jsonEndLocation.getDouble("lng"));
            route.points = decodePolyLine(overview_polylineJson.getString("points"));

            routes.add(route);
        }

        listener.onDirectionFinderSuccess(routes);
    }
```

Comment: You JSON does not seem to be valid

Comment: Can you provide a complete valid JSON with `routes` and `legs` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is your JSON (I tried to deduce it from your extraction code). Please correct it if it is not the JSON you have and I will modify my answer accordingly.

```
{
  "routes" : [ {
      "overview_polyline": {},
      "legs" : [ {
          "distance" : { "text" : "1.3 km", "value" : 1313 },
          "duration" : { "text" : "5 min", "value" : 278 }
        },{
          "distance" : { "text" : "1.9 km", "value" : 1854 },
          "duration" : { "text" : "7 min", "value" : 405 }
        } ]
    },{
      "overview_polyline": {},
      "legs" : [ {
          "distance" : { "text" : "1.4 km", "value" : 1420 },
          "duration" : { "text" : "6 min", "value" : 305 }
        },{
          "distance" : { "text" : "2.1 km", "value" : 2100 },
          "duration" : { "text" : "9 min", "value" : 540 }
        } ]
    } ]
}
```

You need to iterate through the legs to add them and calculate the total values for your route. I removed all what has nothing to do with distance and duration for clarity.

```
private void parseJSon(String data) throws JSONException {
    if (data == null)
        return;

    List<Route> routes = new ArrayList<>();
    JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject(data);
    JSONArray jsonRoutes = jsonData.getJSONArray("routes");
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonRoutes.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonRoute = jsonRoutes.getJSONObject(i);
        Route route = new Route();

        JSONObject overview_polylineJson = jsonRoute.getJSONObject("overview_polyline");
        JSONArray jsonLegs = jsonRoute.getJSONArray("legs");
        double routeDistanceText = 0d;
        int routeDistanceValue = 0;
        int routeDurationText = 0;
        int routeDurationValue = 0;
        for (int legIndex = 0; legIndex < jsonLegs.length(); legIndex++) {
            JSONObject jsonLeg = jsonLegs.getJSONObject(legIndex);
            JSONObject jsonDistance = jsonLeg.getJSONObject("distance");
            JSONObject jsonDuration = jsonLeg.getJSONObject("duration");

            // extract leg distance text as a double
            String legDistanceTextString = jsonDistance.getString("text");
            double legDistanceText = Double.valueOf(legDistanceTextString.substring(0, legDistanceTextString.indexOf(" ")));

            // extract leg distance value as an integer
            int legDistanceValue = jsonDistance.getInt("value");

            // extract leg duration text as an integer
            String legDurationTextString = jsonDuration.getString("text");
            int legDurationText = Integer.valueOf(legDurationTextString.substring(0, legDurationTextString.indexOf(" ")));

            // extract leg duration value as an integer
            int legDurationValue = jsonDuration.getInt("value");

            // add leg values to route values
            routeDistanceText += legDistanceText;
            routeDistanceValue += legDistanceValue;
            routeDurationText += legDurationText;
            routeDurationValue += legDurationValue;
        }

        // add back km and min to distance and duration texts
        String routeDistanceTextString = routeDistanceText + " km";
        String routeDurationTextString = routeDurationText + " min";

        Log.i("TAG", "route: "+i);
        Log.i("TAG", "routeDistanceText: "+routeDistanceTextString);
        Log.i("TAG", "routeDistanceValue: "+routeDistanceValue);
        Log.i("TAG", "routeDurationText: "+routeDurationTextString);
        Log.i("TAG", "routeDurationValue: "+routeDurationValue);

        route.distance = new Distance(routeDistanceTextString, routeDistanceValue);
        route.duration = new Duration(routeDurationTextString, routeDurationValue);

        routes.add(route);
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
route: 0
routeDistanceText: 3.2 km
routeDistanceValue: 3167
routeDurationText: 12 min
routeDurationValue: 683
route: 1
routeDistanceText: 3.5 km
routeDistanceValue: 3520
routeDurationText: 15 min
routeDurationValue: 845
```